# Is WebRTC perfect negotiation necessary?

Tags: webrtc, negotiate

I've been working on WebRTC for a while, and I've implemented WebRTC on Web, Android, iOS, but I don't understand if perfect negotiation is really necessary, because I didn't implement perfect negotiation, but it still works smoothly, I have the following doubt.

1. In what year was the concept of perfect negotiation first introduced? Because when I first started learning WebRTC, I had never heard of such a concept.
2. My current understanding of perfect negotiation is to allow the state machine to return to normal when an offer collision occurs. If I clearly define the offer and answer of both parties, is it possible for offer collision to occur?
3. Suppose there are three devices, A, B, and C. B sends an offer to A, but before receiving an answer from A, C sends an offer to B. Is this a so-called offer collision?
4. In the context of the third question, even if I implement a perfect negotiation and allow B to successfully establish a connection with C, will A be discarded? Or can perfect negotiation allow A, B, and C to all successfully establish a connection?

Comment: "Is it necessary?" — Well, it's a ["best practices" pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation) for how to use the arguably somewhat cumbersome WebRTC API to receive the desired outcome. It's not *necessary* to follow it, but it has proven robust in practice. You're free to use other patterns if you wish.

Comment: It is what someone working at Mozilla decided to be a best practice and it is worth noting that Mozilla is not running a video conferencing service of their own these days.. In reality, it turned out to be far from "perfect" and ignored that some signaling already defined glare handling outside the scope of WebRTC.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Thank you for answering my doubts. If I already have well-defined offer and answer signals, the so-called glare should be unlikely to occur.

Comment: The most common situation where glare occures if one uses one peerconnection for audio, video and screensharing and both sides start sharing their screen at the same time by creating offers. Which presumes those parties don't talk which makes it somewhat theoretical in practice